# AWS Glue pySpark Filter & Manual Mapping of Several Columns

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue Studio with DynamicFrameCollections. I created a custom transformation where I am looking to filter by multiple columns and modify 2 column in the row based off a static mapping list. I'm struggling to figure out what the most efficient way to do this - pandas, udfs, or something completely different?

Consider the sample dataframe:

```
data = [{"Category": 'A', "Subcategory": 2, "Value": 121.44, "Properties": {}},
        {"Category": 'B', "Subcategory": 2, "Value": 300.01, "Properties": None},
        {"Category": 'C', "Subcategory": 3, "Value": 10.99, "Properties": { "Active":True } },
        {"Category": 'E', "Subcategory": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Properties": { "Active":True, "ReadOnly": False }},
        {"Category": 'E', "Subcategory": 1, "Value": 11.37, "Properties": { "Active":True }}
        ] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

I need to filter and transform by `Category` and `Subcategory`. Below is the sample mapping with the key as the category and subcategory merged while the first value in the array must be created as a new column `ActivityName` and the second values must be merged with the `Properties` column:

```
mapping= {"A2": ["EatingFood", { "Visible": True }],
          "A3": ["DrinkingWater", { "Visible": False }],
          "B2": ["Sleep", { "Visible": False }],
          "C3": ["Exercise", { "Visible": False }],
          "E4": ["Running", { "Visible": False }],
}
```

The output data I am expecting is:

```
resultingData = [{"Category": 'A', "Subcategory": 2, "ActivityName":"EatingFood", "Value": 121.44, "Properties": { "Visible": True }},
        {"Category": 'B', "Subcategory": 2, "ActivityName":"Sleep", "Value": 300.01, "Properties": {"Visible": False}},
        {"Category": 'C', "Subcategory": 3, "ActivityName":"Exercise", "Value": 10.99, "Properties": { "Active":True, "Visible": False } },
        {"Category": 'E', "Subcategory": 4, "ActivityName":"Running", "Value": 33.87, "Properties": { "Active":True, "ReadOnly": False, "Visible": False }}
        ]
```

Note that the last data entry, E1 is missing because it was not in my mapping filter.

Is there any way to achieve this? I have a large list of items that I need to manually filter/map/transform like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by transforming the dynamicframe into a dataframe and processing it using glue functions. Here's what I did:

```
def FilterAndMap (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
    from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
    import pyspark.sql.functions as f
    import json
    
    mapping= {"A2": ["EatingFood", json.dumps({ "Visible": True })],
              "A3": ["DrinkingWater", json.dumps({ "Visible": False })],
              "B2": ["Sleep", json.dumps({ "Visible": False })],
              "C3": ["Exercise", json.dumps({ "Visible": False })],
              "E4": ["Running", json.dumps({ "Visible": False })],
    }
    
    
    df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
    
    
    def func_filter_udf(concat_str):
        return mapping[concat_str]
    
    
    def func_map_udf(map_str):
        if map_str[1]:
            map_string = json.loads(map_str[0])
            ret_val = json.dumps({**map_string, **json.loads(map_str[1])})
        else:
            ret_val = map_str[0]
        return ret_val
    
    
    filter_udf = f.udf(func_filter_udf, ArrayType(StringType()))
    map_udf = f.udf(func_map_udf, StringType())
    
    df = df.filter(f.concat("Category", "Subcategory").isin([*mapping]))
    
    df = df.withColumn("concat_col", filter_udf(f.concat("Category", "Subcategory")))
    df = (df.withColumn("ActivityName", df.concat_col[0]).
      withColumn("Properties", map_udf(f.struct(df.concat_col[1], df.Properties))))
    
    df = df.drop("concat_col")
    
    
    dyf_processed = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "filtered")
    
    return(DynamicFrameCollection({"filtered": dyf_processed }, glueContext))
```